# Java triangle with for loops or else

Tags: java, for-loop

I need to create a right triangle starting on the right working left.
Ex. (–'s are spaces)

––––X 
–––XX
––XXX
–XXXX
XXXXX

A number (and the character; ex X) will be give before hand in runner. Which the code I was given. I need code to make triangle. For example if the number was 5 each line would add up to 5 characters counting from one X with 4 spaces. Then there would be 5 rows last would be all X's.

Update:
My code prints out

––––X
–––X
––X
–X
X
(–'s spaces, no spaces after character)

Comment: Please show us your code. Sounds like you are half way there.. p.s. hurry up if you want to avoid getting this question closed.

Comment: I think you forgot to *ask a question*.

Comment: Your first edit was better than your current edit!!

Comment: Need code to fix what mine which prints out bottom lines

Comment: Need to first show your code. Voting to close as a non-question.

Comment: @Pradeep Simha. What do u mean??

Comment: I mean your previous edit was better readable than current

Comment: Sorry I am not being clear I am trying to do this on my phone, I don't have any wifi to do this on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's start with the number 5. The best bet is to simply think about what has to be output on each line and then loop over the lines doing that.

With that number, you have to output 5 lines as follows (I'll use `.` for spaces since it's easier to discern adjacent ones):

```
....X
...XX
..XXX
.XXXX
XXXXX
```

Look at each line as follows:

- The first line has 4 spaces and an `x`.
- The second line has 3 spaces and 2 `x`'s.
- The third line has 2 spaces and 3 `x`'s.
- The fourth line has 1 spaces and 4 `x`'s.
- The fifth line has no spaces and 5 `x`'s.

I sense a pattern here ((4,1), (3,2), (2,3), (1,4), (0,5)) - the first number starts at `n-1` (4 in this case) and decreases to 0. The second number starts at 1 and increases to `n` (5 in this case).

In pseudo-code (which is all you get from me for homeworky-type questions), it looks something like:

```
def maketriangle (n):
    for lineidx = 1 to n:
        for charidx = 1 to n - lineidx:   // 4 3 2 1 0
            output " "
        for charidx = 1 to lineidx:       // 1 2 3 4 5
            output "X"
        output newline
```

Your job is to then convert that into real code.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assuming you want to print `n` x `n` fields and the current row index is `i`. Then you need to print X `n-i` times (or `n-i-1` times depending if your index `i` starts at 0 or at 1)